# Edit a function regarding organizing tables

Tags: r

I have a function that looks as:

```
organize.table <- function(x,y = NULL, col = NULL, row = NULL, sort = NULL, sort.row = sort,
                       sort.col = sort, total = TRUE, other = TRUE, ...){

  if((!is.factor(x) & !is.character(x)) | (!is.factor(y) & !is.character(y))){
    stop("Either x or y is not a factor", call. = FALSE)
  }
 if(length(x) != length(y)){
    stop("Length of x not equal to y", call. = FALSE)
 }
 if(!(sort.row %in% c('desc', 'asc')) | is.null(sort.row) |
    !(sort.col %in% c('desc', 'asc')) |  is.null(sort.col)){
    stop("sort.row or sort.col not equal to NULL, 'desc', or 'asc'")
 }
 if((!is.null(sort.row) | !is.null(sort.col)) & total == FALSE){
   stop("To use sort.row or sort.col, parameter 'total' must equal TRUE", call. = FALSE)
 }
 if(length(unique(y)) <= col | length(unique(x)) <= row){
   stop("Error: Dimension mismatch between x and col or y and row. col < the unique number of 
     attributes in y or row < the unique number of attributes in x", call. = FALSE)
 }
 tabs <- table(x,y, ...)
 cs   <- ncol(tabs)
 rs   <- nrow(tabs)
 if(total == TRUE){
   tabs           <- cbind(tabs, rowSums(tabs))
   colname.tabs   <- c(colnames(tabs)[1:cs], 'Total')
   colnames(tabs) <- colname.tabs
   tabs           <- rbind(tabs, colSums(tabs))
   rowname.tabs   <- c(rownames(tabs)[1:rs], 'Total')
   rownames(tabs) <- rowname.tabs
 }
if(sort.row == 'desc') {
   tabs <- tabs[order(-tabs$Total), ]
   tabs <- tabs[rowname.tabs,]
 }
if(sort.row == 'asc')  {
   tabs <- tabs[order( tabs$Total), ]
   tabs <- rowname.tabs
 }
if(sort.col == 'desc') {
   tabs <- tabs[ ,order(-tabs['Total', ])]
   tabs <- colname.tabs
 }
 if(sort.col == 'asc') {
   tabs <- tabs[ ,order( tabs['Total', ])]
   tabs <- colname.tabs
 }
 if(other == TRUE){
   ra   <- row + 1; ca <- col + 1
    tabs <- cbind(tabs[ ,1:col], rowSums(tabs[ ,ca:cs]), tabs$Total)
    tabs <- rbind(tabs[1:row, ], colSums(tabs[ra:rs, ]), tabs['Total',])
    rownames(tabs) <- c(rownames(tabs)[1:row], 'Other', 'Total')
    colnames(tabs) <- c(colnames(tabs)[1:col], 'Other', 'Total')
  }
}
```

Often times when working I am required to produce a two way table that requires the top *ncol* and *nrow* values from this table and summarize the remainder of the table as **Other** for both columns and rows. Also, I generally need a **Total** column and row. Sometimes I need the fewest (least) *ncol* and *nrow* values. This is actually meant to be a flexible table function. I am getting errors, namely:

> **Error in tabs$Total : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**.

Any recommendations or codes on fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

In both of the `if` statements

```
if(sort.col == 'desc') {
   tabs <- tabs[ ,order(-tabs['Total', ])]
   tabs <- colname.tabs
}
if(sort.col == 'asc') {
   tabs <- tabs[ ,order( tabs['Total', ])]
   tabs <- colname.tabs
}
```

you set `tabs <- colname.tabs`.  Once you do that, tabs is just a vector,
not a data.frame so in the subsequent line when you try to use `tabs$Total`,
you get this error.   I think that instead of `tabs <- colname.tabs` 
your really wanted `colnames(tabs)  <- colname.tabs`.

I see that you also have one of your `if` statements that includes
`tabs <- rowname.tabs`. That should probably be 
`rownames(tabs) <- rowname.tabs`

#### Reproducing the error

Your function is too complex for me to reproduce the error from your 
function, but I can get the same error message in a simple example.

```
colname.tabs   <- c(colnames(iris)[1:4], 'Total')
colname.tabs 
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Total"

colname.tabs$Total
Error in colname.tabs$Total : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```